# What is the alternative for deprecated springfox ClassOrApiAnnotationResourceGrouping class?

Tags: java, springfox, deprecation-warning

I am using 2.4.0. version of the spring-fox. `ClassOrApiAnnotationResourceGrouping` class is giving deprecated warning while building. In [1] there are no alternatives provided, it only says deprecated. One of the comment in [2] says that it will be used until next release, but how can I avoid getting these warnings while building from cmd?

Relative links:

[1]http://springfox.github.io/springfox/javadoc/2.7.0/springfox/documentation/swagger/web/ClassOrApiAnnotationResourceGrouping.html

[2]https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1307

Comment: Update with latest released version

Comment: It gives the same warnings for 2.7.0. version, nothing changes

Comment: Can you print your exception print stack, It's help us to figure out the exact issue may apringfox or It's Compile Dependencies

Comment: D:\....\ClassOrApiAnnotationResourceGroupingExternalizer.java:10:
arning: [deprecation] ClassOrApiAnnotationResourceGrouping in springfox.documenation.swagger.web has been deprecated
import springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ClassOrApiAnnotationResourceGrouping;

Comment: If you look this link and search **ClassOrApiAnnotationResourceGrouping** http://springfox.github.io/springfox/javadoc/2.7.0/index.html?springfox/documentation/service/ApiInfo.html You will find Class ClassOrApiAnnotationResourceGrouping and https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/master/springfox-swagger-common/src/main/java/springfox/documentation/swagger/web/ClassOrApiAnnotationResourceGrouping.java Deprecated.

Comment: Yes I know that already, my question is what is the replacement for this?

Comment: Check my answer, I thing It's help you to resolve your  springfox deprecated class issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To use ClassOrApiAnnotationResourceGrouping Deprecated class in
>   springfox dependency library to group using Api annotation.

Configure the blah bean with an implementation of the resource grouping strategy

Replacement for this Deprecated Api annotation of class **ClassOrApiAnnotationResourceGrouping** is

```
apiListingReferenceScanner.setResourceGroupingStrategy(springSwaggerConfig.defaultResourceGroupingStrategy());
```

More: https://github.com/komoot/swagger-springmvc

**Deprecated** Class **ClassOrApiAnnotationResourceGrouping** springfox info **:**
  http://springfox.github.io/springfox/javadoc/2.7.0/index.html?springfox/documentation/service/ApiInfo.html

Comment: How can I have that springSwaggerConfig instance?